# Discord.py code doesn't work! How can i fix this?

Tags: python, discord.py

Why does not this work? When I run the code and try the !test, it doesn't even send an error to the terminal. How can i fix this?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")




bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    ctx.send("test")
    
    
    
    
bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the decorator symbol

```
@bot.command()
```

also, the send message instruction inside your `test` function needs to be awaited

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")
```